# Connect ios devices to local server via wifi

Tags: ios, localhost, wireless

I have a localhost server on my laptop. Can I connect ios device to this localhost server through wifi?
What settings I must set up on wifi connection?

Answer (score 2):

By localhost server , i assume you are talking about a HTTP server .
If you know the port on which the server is listening to , note it down.
If you dont , generally web servers are attached to port 80.

If both laptop and ios device is connected to the same network.
Then first note down the IPAddress of you laptop.

In windows you can do so by typing : ipconfig in the command prompt
In Unix or Linux based systems : type ifconfig in the terminal.
Lets assume you found out that your ipaddress is 192.168.1.2

Note down this IP Address of your wifi adapter.

Now , just type in  IPAddress:Port in the web browser of your ios device to access the server.
eg: Type in 192.168.1.2:80 on the url bar of ios device.